# Problem with APTonCD application

Tags: 10.10, package-management

I created a iso image using aptoncd & burned it to a dvd. Now when i tried to restore, the program does not detect the dvd in the drive. It shows "Please insert a disc in the drive." and if we click "ok" it shows `E: Failed to mount the cdrom`. The dvd is in the drive itself.

I tried `sudo lshw -C disk` and the output is:

```
*-cdrom
   description: DVD-RAM writer
   product: DVDRAM GH22NS50
   vendor: HL-DT-ST
   physical id: 1
   bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/cdrom
   logical name: /dev/cdrw
   logical name: /dev/dvd
   logical name: /dev/dvdrw
   logical name: /dev/scd0
   logical name: /dev/sr0
   logical name: /media/APTonCD
   logical name: /media/apt
   version: TN02
   capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
   configuration: ansiversion=5 mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500 state=mounted status=ready
 *-medium
      physical id: 0
      logical name: /dev/cdrom
      logical name: /media/APTonCD
      logical name: /media/apt
      configuration: mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500 state=mounted
```

Then i checked in disk utility application. in that dvd rom is shown as `/dvd/sr0`

My ubuntu version is 10.10.

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: How did you burn the iso to the DVD ? Can you read other DVDs ?

Comment: I also faced this problem. Any info how to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If the DVD is readable, you can copy the packages manually to

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/
```

That will make all the packages available for synaptic/software-center to use.

**And to do so**, run this command in a terminal:

```
sudo rsync -avp /media/cdrom/packages/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote up a quick script for fixing this, provided your DVD is readable. The problem is, in fact, that the CD/DVD is mounted dynamically, and mounts with the disc's label, instead of the generic /media/cdrom mount.

Open a text editor, and copy/paste this, then save as APTonCD-install.sh:

```
#!bin/bash
# This script is for installing APTonCD backups from a dynamically-mounted CD/DVD-ROM.

# Sync archive
sudo rsync -avp /media/APTonCD/packages/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/

# Install software
sudo apt-get update

# Exit Script
exit 0
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the original iso created by aptoncd you can do a restore from that directly. Follow the wizard through choosing

Screen1: choose option **restore**

Screen2: choose option **load**

Screen3: choose option **iso image** you can browse to your iso image that you made before burning and it will load your packages for selection and let you restore.

If you do not have the original iso still, I am sorry but I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the DVD image is broken or not burned correctly. This could have been any number of issues.

First thing to do is to check the dvd in another computer to confirm if it works or not there.

If it does, then you have an odd problem with your Ubuntu machine, and you should try some other dvds in that drive.

If it doesn't, then you may need to try and create another dvd.

Comment: not solved. DVD image is ok. but problem is APTonCD application not detecting it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better script

```
#!bin/bash
# This script is for installing APTonCD backups from a dynamically-mounted CD/DVD-ROM.

# Sync archive
sudo rsync -avp /media/APTonCD/packages/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/

# Change path
cd /var/cache/apt/archives/

# Install software
sudo dpkg -i *.deb

# Install missing dependencies if any
sudo apt-get install -f

# Exit Script
exit 0
exit
```